# How to generate points belonging to some region very fast?

Tags: performance-tuning, random, compile

Consider two variables `Ex,th`. `th` ranges within

```
thmin=10^-5;
thmax=Pi/2;
```

while `Ex` - within

```
ExMin=5.3;
ExMax[th_] =
  5000*Interpolation[
     Table[{10^x, Cos[10^x]^7}, {x, -5, Log10[Pi/2], 0.05}], 
     InterpolationOrder -> 1][th];
```

I have made such a weird function `ExMax` instead of just `5000*Cos[th]^7` to imitate my real task, where it is some complicated interpolation.

I need to generate random points belonging to this domain. This is what I do:

```
RandomAnglesEnergies = 
  Hold@Compile[{\[Theta]min, \[Theta]max, Emin, Emax}, 
    Module[{\[Theta]v = 0., Ev = 0.}, 
     While[\[Theta]v = RandomReal[{\[Theta]min, \[Theta]max}];
      Ev = RandomReal[{Emin, Emax}];
      Ev >= ExMax[\[Theta]v]];
     {\[Theta]v, Ev}], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. DownValues@ExMax;
```

The approach **is slow**:

```
Table[RandomAnglesEnergies[thmin, thmax, ExMin, 5000], 10^5]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.25,Null}

Could you please tell me how to speedup it up further (if possible)?

Comment: You can move interpolation outside the loop.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling

Comment: What I mean: First sample the $\theta$-coodinate according to the probability distribution defined by the interpolation function (modulo normalization) via inverse transform sampling. Then sample the vertical coordinate uniformly in  the interval from `ExMin` to `ExMax[th]`. This way you don't have to reject any single draw.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher : my problem is that the interpolation function itself evaluates very long.

Comment: I ran the code as-is and got the following result:
{0.0361593, Null}
This is using MM13.2 on an Intel Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz, 2592 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 12 Logical Processor(s)